# What are the different methods and their respective odds of getting/earning character specific items?

Tags: final-fantasy-record-keeper

I've just started playing Final Fantasy Record Keeper and managed to unlock Aerith, along with earning Cloud, Kain, and a few other early characters. I know that all of these characters have rare items that are specific to them, such as the Buster Sword for Cloud. So far, I've only seen people mention receiving these items from the rare item relic pulls.

What are the different ways of earning character-specific items? Are there any conditions before being eligible (like perhaps unlocking a character before their item is available)? Are the odds of each method known if they are, what are those odds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're referring to the 5* items that can allow a new soul break to be used when a specific character equips it (e.g. Hell's Gate when Sephiroth equips Masamune, Healing Wind when Aerith equips Guard Stick), those are only available through relic pulls. Note that 5* equipment is not limited to rare relic pulls as it is possible obtain any piece of equipment from the daily free common relic pull.

There are no offically published numbers on relic pulls (at least for Global), but here is the best information I was able to find on the probabilities:

Rare Relic:
3*: 75%
4*: 20%
5*: 5%

Common Relic (percentages rounded a little):
1*: 73.9%
2*: 20%
3*: 6%
4*: 0.08%
5*: 0.01%

(Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/FFRecordKeeper/comments/31lidm/comparing_the_rate_of_relic_pulls_of_japan_and/)

Comment: Well... let's just say I'm not optimistic at ever coming across a 5* item with a new soul break for one of my characters.

Comment: @Ellesedil Keep in mind that the character specific items have significantly boosted drop rates during events, which helps a lot.

Comment: It can also help if you save up your mythril until you have 50.  That gives you a free pull (11 pulls for the price of 10)

Comment: Also, it seems as though the drop rate of 5* equipment rises to 10% (which lowers the 3* drop rate) when there is a relic event where multiple characters see an increased drop rate (like the Wakka, Kain, Rydia, Cloud one that recently ended)