# Are characters obtainable during events also obtainable during the normal campaign?

Tags: final-fantasy-record-keeper

When I initially started playing, there was an active event that was nearly over in order to acquire Sephiroth. But being so new, I wasn't in any position to compete for it.

Are characters that are offered during events like Sephiroth and Aerith also obtainable during the storyline of the game much like Cloud and Wakka are?

Comment: Knowing these games, probably not.

Comment: This is important to me, too.  I started playing when they sent me an email saying "Sephiroth has been added as a recruitable character!"  but clearly wasn't powerful enough to get Sephie during that event.  If he's actually non-recruitable now, that's probably the end of my record-keeping days.

Comment: @gatherer818: I'm in a similar boat. Between the limited availability of characters and the [rarity of their corresponding 5* equipment](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/214755/what-are-the-different-methods-and-their-respective-odds-of-getting-earning-char), I'm definitely reconsidering how much time I'll spend on FFRK. I don't mind working towards stuff, but throwing a ton of money at gems or just not having the opportunity to get stuff I want is somewhat of a turn-off.

Answer (score 2):

Japan has also received a quest system where you get a quest to clear a specific elite dungeon and you can get an event character you missed. So far, only 5 or so of these quests have been released in Japan, but those that have missed Sephiroth, for example, can now get him through this quest system (again,Japan only at least for now).

Comment: US version has added this as well.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, *However* supposedly some events have repeated in the Japanese version of the game, offering a second shot at the limited time characters you may have missed.

Comment: Well that's good news. Sorta.

Answer (score 1):

The Hall of Rites has been added to the game. You can go there to exchange "Soul of a Hero", "Memory Crystal Lode" and "Memory Crystal II Lode" items to get any character and their associated Memory Crystals that has previously been available. Specifically for this question, Sephiroth and Aerith both appear to be available.

In addition, if you also already have all of the heroes and their first Memory Crystals you can trade in the "Soul of a Hero" and "Memory Crystal Lode" items for a Growth Egg. Not all characters have a "Memory Crystal II Lode" so it appears that the Growth Egg option is not available yet.